# Why did I not get the Tag Editor badge?

Tags: support, badges

I edited [suhosin](/questions/tagged/suhosin)  [yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/8402613/revisions).

I still have not received the [Tag Editor](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/73/tag-editor) badge.

Did I not understand the requirements correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't *edit* the tag wiki; you *created* it. The badge is only awarded for editing existing wikis.

Comment: Thats odd. technically creating is a form of editing lol. So if I edit my created tag wiki I should be good? (that still makes no sense at all....)

Comment: Don't look at me, I didn't make the rule. You asked a question, I answered it.

Comment: Do you have a reference?

Comment: It's noted in [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/68258/131713). The original source for _that_ was [Grace Note saying that waffles said so](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/67399/7).

Comment: Hmmmm that is quite silly lol.

Comment: No, it makes perfect sense. Creating and editing are different things, that's why the [CRUD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) isn't called RUD.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that sometimes the badges take a while to get. You won't immediately receive the badge. I'm sure that some time in the near future, if you really did do what was required for the tag editor badge, then you will get the badge.