# Why did Community ♦ pre-plagiarize my tag wiki entry?

Tags: discussion, tags, badges, edit-badges

Yesterday I could've *sworn* that I *created* both the tag [wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/8409849/revisions) and [excerpt](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/8409850/revisions) for [s3cmd](/questions/tagged/s3cmd).  However, I was awarded the Tag Editor badge and after seeing [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/115168), I went to look at the [history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/8409849/revisions) only to find that Community♦ had apparently beaten me to it.

What's worse, looking through Community♦'s (hard to link to) activity, I see that contrary to what's in the history, Community♦ actually wrote *exactly what I wrote*, ***before I wrote it!***
[image: Pre-plagiarism!]

**So what are the recommended steps for dealing with pre-plagiarism on SO?**

<sup>(Really though, what's going on?  Is this some hack to give tag wiki creators the Tag Editor badge?)</sup>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When the tag wiki doesn't exist, and you are creating it, it's really Community♦ that creates an empty tag wiki, to which is then added your proposed edit, when it gets approved.

Only 20k users can edit any tag wiki present in a site; in that case, the tag wiki is not first created by Community♦.

[image: screenshot]